# GET call with node js with headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, get

This my code for doing a REST call. I have tried with POSTMAN rest call and the url and headers are ok. But with node js I am not able to do this

**I have not given the real API key and url here**

```
/**
 * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
 */
// options for GET
var optionsget = {
    host : 'abcd.com:80/edwde/wedwed/', // here only the domain name
    // (no http/https !)
    //port : 443,
    //path : '/youscada', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    headers : getheaders,
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};

var getheaders = {
    'x-api-key' : 'diudnwod87wedh8778=',
    'content-type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

This is the reference of my code: http://isolasoftware.it/2012/05/28/call-rest-api-with-node-js/

**I have edited my code and it is working:**

```
var http = require('http');
/**
 * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
 */
// options for GET
var getheaders = {
    'x-api-key' : 'diudnwod87wedh8778=',
    'content-type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

};

var optionsget = {
    host : 'abcd.com', // here only the domain name
    // (no http/https !)
    port : 80,
    path : '/edwde/wedwed/', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    headers : getheaders,
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};



console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = http.request(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the output exactly?
Also, you reference getheaders in optionsget before having actually declared getheaders.

Comment: I have corrected the get header ie. declared getheader b4 options get but the same error
Output:

[Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abcd.com:80/edwde/wedwed/]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'abcd.com:80/edwde/wedwed/' }

Comment: I think that you should separate the host and the path, the host being abcd.com and the path being /edwde/wedwed/

Comment: Thank you . I have corrected my code in edit and it is working. Thanks a lot for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library.